# Как понять, почему закрывается Activity

Tags: android, activity

Есть задача, для которой требуется узнать в `onDestroy` в результате чего закрывается `Activity`, например в результате нажатия кнопки "назад" или переворота экрана.

---

Как узнать из-за чего, в данный момент, закрывается `Activity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути у `onDestroy()` тернарное состояние:

1. Нажатие back
2. Поворот экрана
3. Вызов `finish()` инициированный или программно или самой осью

Возможно есть и другие причины (коллеги укажут есличо).

Нажатие back легко отслеживается через `onBackPressed()`, 
поворот экрана через `onConfigurationChanged()`. Если дополнить эти методы еще и предложенным выше `isFinishing()` - то можно вполне детектировать причину `onDestroy()`

Comment: Точно! Вот про что я забыл! В голове сидело, что есть какой-то метод, который вызывается при смене ориентации, а какой — не помнил. И самое смешное, что, после прочтения Вашего ответа, сразу наткнулся на него в гугле. В первой ссылке... :)

Answer (score 1):

Для этого есть метод `isFinishing`. Если этот метод возвращает `true` то активити умирает, т.е. нажали кнопку "назад". Если `false`, то значит идет переворот экрана

Comment: Метод возвращает `true`, когда вызывается `finish()` для активити, а это больше вариантов, чем только "назад". И `false` будет возвращенно во многих случаях, не только при повороте. Например,  при нажатии кнопки "Домой", вместо "Назад" или открытии другого приложения и еще множества состояний. Это надо учитывать, все не так однозначно, как в вашем ответе (то есть, метод не индикатор поворота)

Comment: Это понятно))). Просто не понятно какой кейс у человека. А это как пример, на что можно опираться